# Is "declarer" a French word or a spelling mistake?

Tags: sens, orthographe

I know the verb *déclarer* with *é* means to declare. However, is the *declarer without é* also a French word?

This question arose in my mind while I was reading the textbook for *French in Action*. There's a sentence on page 27 which reads exactly: *Il n'a rien à declarer.*

EDIT: Looking up in online dictionaries didn't work as many online dictionaries aggregate words algorithmically which leads to them collecting wrong usages of words as well. *Declarer* can be found in some online French dictionaries.

Comment: Probably a typing/printing error. Indeed the accent should be there. No such French word as /declarer/.

Comment: @None Please write this as an answer so that I may accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indeed there's no such word as <del>declarer</del> in French, and, as you supposed, it should be written *d**é**clarer*. It's either a typing error or a printing error. If the book was printed in the 21st century, the way books have been made over the past few decades with publishers sending ready to print files to the printer's, it is a typing error. If the book is old enough to have been printed the old way with letterpress printing and such, then could be a printing error.